# How to get around incorrect warning in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

I'm receiving the following warning:

```
Instance method 'method name' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

when this code is invoked:

```
@protocol SomeProtocol <NSObject> {
    @property (nonatomic, retain) SpecificClassName* someDelegate;
}
...
+ (void) aMethod : (id <SomeProtocol>) object {
    [object.someDelegate doSomeThing]; // warning statement show up here
}
```

I feel like this is a short coming of the compiler at this point, but that just may be the pot calling the kettle black ... does anyone have any feedback on this?

Comment: Maybe you need to `#import` the header file for SpecificClassName?

Comment: do you implemented methods: `someDelegate` and `setSomeDelegate` in your class that conforms that `SomeProtocol`?

Comment: @joerick - Thanks a lot! can you please make it an actual answer so that I may mark it as accepted? ... Adding the import statement did the trick, i wasn't actively using a variable that would require the SpecificClassName to be imported but I was indeed fetching it via property getter (object.someDelegate) and due to that "the import of SpecificClassName" became non-obvious to me but necessary according to the compiler warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `#import` the header file for `SpecificClassName`, in your implementation (`.m` file).

If you're going to use the type name `SpecificClassName` in the header file, a forward declaration `@class SpecificClassName` will do, but calling a method on the class requires the compiler to know the return type of the method.

If you want to call a method on an instance of `SpecificClassName`, include the header in which it's defined.

Answer (score 0):

I means that the header file for the class doesn't include the method signature. So the compiler can't tell if the method is actually there. Fix the header file to get rid of the warning.

In Java or C++, this would be a compilation failure. That's because they do method binding at compile-time, so the compiler needs to *find* the methods. Objective-C does it at run-time; it sends a method call to an object, and the object may or may not have such a method.

Comment: I am using a protocol and that DOES include the method signature, so the implementing class DOES NOT need to have that included in its header file again.